# passing down values to an IIFE function

Tags: javascript, iife

This might be a stupid question but I have looked everywhere and coming to SO as the last resort. 
        My doubt is an IIFE function usually looks like this

```
var me = (function() { /*code*/} )();
me();
```

I have not seen any code that has variables passed down into it so far.
Is it possible to pass down values to an IIFE function? I have already tried using

```
var Person = (function(name,age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
     }());
  Person("Bob Smith", 30);
```

which gives me an undefined error.

So is there a way to pass down these values into an IIFE or should it be avoided?

Comment: Why are you using an IFEE to define a constructor? At least you should return a function! In your case Person returns undefined, you cannot use it as a constructor

Comment: Thanks, I'm still quite confused on when to use IIFEs.

Comment: IIFE is a function which is instantly invoked. You can set your params in the IIFE itself: `(function(x) {console.log(x);})(123)` will log 123, but doing `var f = function(x) {console.log(x);}; f(123)` produces **exactly the same** result

Comment: Thanks, it's starting to make sense but is it possible to pass down values to an IIFE ?  lets say I want to add two numbers by passing down the values a and b. Sorry, if it sounds very stupid.

Comment: I think you are a bit confused about functions in JS, I recommend you these readings: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-this-construct-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks, I will. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be an IIFE with parameters:

```
(function (a, b) {
    alert(a + b);
}('hello', ' world'));
```

---

---

What you seem to be doing, as others said, is a constructor, so there's no need for them there.

You could do a constructor this way if you wanted:

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

var bob = new Person('Bob Smith', 30);
```

You could do an anonymously invoked constructor, but that's pointless since it's a one-use type of deal, and you wouldn't need a constructor for that.